# Order of Java Config SecurityBuilder's

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm developing a web application unsing Spring Security 4.0.0's  Java Config instead of xml config. I'm using `ObjectPostProcessor`s to customize the some of Spring Security's beans, notably the session consurrency ones (to achive immediate invalidation of a session as soon as a user logs in again, as opposed to Spring's standard behavior of invalidating at the next request).

It's working as expected most of the times, but sometimes when I restart the application it seems like not all beans get modified as I want.

Are `SecurityBuilder`s processed in a specific order or are they instead processed with a ramdom order?

EDIT:

### My Config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends AbstractCASWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true, false, true);
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    // we need a custom SessionRegistry as there's no way to get ahold of the one created by the configurer.
    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    // we need a custom HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository as there's no way to get ahold of the one created by the configurer.
    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    }

    // our custom ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy that invalidates session immediately
    @Bean
    public SessionInvalidatingConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy myConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationListener()
    {
        // we have to recreate the LogoutHandlers because we need to call them
        // before invalidating the session

        final LogoutHandler [] logoutHandlers = new LogoutHandler [] { 
                new CookieClearingLogoutHandler("JSESSIONID"),
                new CsrfLogoutHandler(csrfTokenRepository())
                //, new SecurityContextLogoutHandler() // seems to create problems with redirecting to the same page that caused the login request
                };  


        SessionInvalidatingConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy mine = new SessionInvalidatingConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry(), logoutHandlers);
        mine.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(false);
        mine.setMaximumSessions(1);
        return mine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);

        boolean devMode = this.env.acceptsProfiles("development");

        final String [] ignoredPaths = devMode
            ? new String [] {"/webjars/**", "/static/**", "/bower_components/**" } 
            : new String [] {"/webjars/**", "/static/**" };

        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(ignoredPaths)
                .and()
            .debug(false)
        ;
    }

    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(73467436)  // this is just to trigger the ConcurrencyControlConfigurer
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                    .and()
                .withObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy>() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public <O extends ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy> O postProcess(O concurrentSessionControlAS) {
                        // substitute the ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy created by 
                        // ConcurrencyControlConfigurer with our own

                        return (O) myConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationListener();
                    }
                })
                .and()
            // we need to ignore the stomp endpoint to allow SockJS javascript client to issue POST requests
            // to /push/../../.. when using trasports which are not WebSocket;
            // at that time, protection is given by Stomp CSRF headers
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/push/**")
                .and()
            // allow same origin to frame our site to support iframe SockJS
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/help/**").permitAll() // help redirects do not require authentication
                .antMatchers("/push/info").permitAll() // do not require being authenticated for the /info request by SockJS
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            // remove the session cookie when logging out
            .logout()
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID") // see: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#detecting-timeouts
                .and()
            ;

    }


}
```

`AbstractCASWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is an AbstractWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that configures CAS.

Comment: Can you provide your configuration and ObjectPostProcessor?

Comment: @RobWinch Added my confg.